# Fiware: can we push data from one Orion context broker to another?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

can we push data from one Orion context broker to another Orion?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Have a look to the section about [Context Broker federation](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user/federation/) in the documentation about it.